# Scheduled task (defender scan) never launches

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am following the documentation here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/66eb0a31-2a59-4c90-ba5b-23bcdfb6f185/schedule-a-scan-in-windows-defender

But when I do that and create a scheduled defender scan, set the system time to 2 minutes before the scan trigger, and wait, the status of the scan never changes to "running". It just stays at "ready".

What am I doing wrong? Why does my scheduled task not trigger?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I just tried and it still shows that the task has not run and is not currently running.

Comment: Best option is to create a new task rather than adding a trigger to system default task.  The latter one uses a special parameter. For guaranteed scan, create a new task Ref: [How to Schedule a Windows Defender Scan in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/schedule-windows-defender-scan-windows-10/)

Comment: @w32sh Thanks, that's actually pretty helpful but can you clarify what that special parameter is and why it prevents this from working? After all, the documentation I am using is from MS, it should work.

Comment: `Scan -ScheduleJob` which is not documented. My guess is it skips the scan if it's already run by automatic maintenance, or postpones it for some reason.

Comment: @w32sh Thanks. The link you provided worked. If you want rep feel free to post it as an answer - I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a trigger to the in-built Windows Defender task, create a new task for a guaranteed scan. Use this command-line:

> "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"

Set the Arguments as follows:

> -Scan -ScanType 1

For Full scan, use:

> -Scan -ScanType 2

Make sure you configure the task to run as `SYSTEM` user account with highest privileges.

Reference: at [How to Schedule a Windows Defender Scan in Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/schedule-windows-defender-scan-windows-10/)